# Bootstrap's 'navbar' width constraints are killing my menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, menubar

Okay, here goes (first time asking a question, so bear with me and let me know if you could use further information.)

As my title says, I'm using Bootstrap to generate a horizontal menu (called 'navbar' in the CSS) and when I make the screen size a little smaller, the content of the navbar furthest to the right starts disappearing or going to the next line. I would appreciate this (and understand) if it were happening when the width gets close to the content, but it's happening when the width is about 750-768px. In some tests, I have seen the content itself completely go *poof*. Honestly, if someone can even tell me why (and what) is happening I would appreciate it. Heck, it might end up being a great accessibility trick!

What I have discovered so far is a strange little bit of code: @media (min-width: 768px). What's really strange to me is that the Chrome inspector won't even let me alter this thing. That is something I have never seen before. I'll be honest, I'm not too familiar with this formatting property either but my education thus far has not provided enough insight.

[image: screenshot]

Now I'm hoping that this is a problem that someone finds familiar (I've been looking, but no hits) because I'd rather not dump the entire codebase online at this point. If it is necessary, I will comply, but I'm hoping someone can share their own experiences with this problem so I can put down my 'fist of anger'. It's a very angry fist. Trust me.

Shipping is a feature...perhaps the most important feature.

Comment: It's CSS basics called `media-querys`. Start reading about it in the bootstrap context here for example: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: That's what the [`navbar`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) is supposed to do. If you don't want it to disappear, put everything in the `.navbar-header`. If you want more help, you'll probably need to upload ONLY the relevant code that reproduces the issue into a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/kcpma/)

Comment: I would to thank everyone for their generous help. You have saved me a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted above, the behaviour you mention is the Bootstrap default ... you can customise it though.

<strike>The CSS media query  **@media (min-width: 768px) ...** sets the viewport or window width at which the nav menu collapses. If you want to change this, one option is to go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ , scroll down to the media query breakpoints and set @screen-sm to what ever width you want.</strike>

If you go to http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ , scroll to the grid system section you can customise the navbar collapse with @grid-float-breakpoint . Thanks to [cvrebert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3342739/cvrebert) for the correction below

Then go to the bottom of the page and compile and download your customised Bootstrap CSS file.

If you use LESS, you can do something similar as well.

Hope this helps relax the fist of anger ;)

Comment: Actually, the var you want to adjust is `@grid-float-breakpoint`. See the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar